# Move Object auto snaps to full values

Tags: 3d-view

If you hold Ctrl while translating objects move by full values. I must have pressed some buttons accidentally because for some reason right now its the other way around. I have to hold Ctrl while translating everytime to be able to translate an object normally without it snapping to full values. I don't know how to revert this, reopening doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks man I was about to snap myself lol